# Как передать значения из одной функции в другую?

Tags: c++, функции

Как передать значение переменной sum из функции Foo ---> в Foo2 ???

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int Foo(int a, int b)
    {
        int sum;
        sum = a + b;        //2) Складываем полученные значния


        return sum;     //3) Возвращаем результат сложения в функцию Foo

    }

    int Foo2()
    {

        cout << " output "<< sum << endl;
    }

    int main() 
    {

        int a, b;       //1) Получаем 2 значения от пользователя
        cin >> a >> b;
        Foo(a,b);       //4) Передаем значения в Foo для сложения

        Foo2();         //5) С помощью Foo2 выводим результат в консоль

    }
```

Comment: так ведь Foo2 возвращает мусор.. Если она ничего не должна возвращать, то пишите `void Foo2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать через аргумент функции.

```
int Foo2(int sum)
{

    cout << " output "<< sum << endl;
}

...

Foo2(Foo(a,b));
```

Вариант с передачей через глобальную переменную лучше даже не рассматривать...

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.